# Where does macports log its stdout?

Tags: log-files, mac-osx

Does it even log output?  In particular, I'm trying to find out how I can recover those messages about, for example, how to use the updated version of Python, or how to use launchd to start a new app by default.  I schedule macports updates so I almost always miss these messages because I'm not sitting in front of my computer when the updates occur.

TIA!

Comment: Starting with MacPorts 1.8.2 (it's in trunk for now) there is a logging mechanism.

Comment: The logging feature Nerdling referred to will be part of MacPorts 1.9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently MacPorts has no notion of logging of build activities of a given port or sets of ports, however you can pipe the output (stderr and stdout) to a file for later viewing.

> `port upgrade outdated 2>&1 >> updates.txt`

Comment: Incidentally, you can also use `port upgrade outdated &>> updates.txt` if that's easier to remember.

Comment: I recommend using `port upgrade outdated 2>&1 | tee updates.txt` which prints to both the terminal and to the file. This allows to see progress.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest redirecting the output of your executions of `port` so that you can review the information at a later time.

A cursory `find` in /opt/local doesn't bring up anything useful.